# conflicts of mongoose dependency with nestjs nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

i have this package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.2.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/serve-static": "^2.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "find-config": "^1.0.0",
    "html-pdf-node": "^1.0.8",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "~8.0.4",
```

and i am trying to install this

```
npm i @typegoose/auto-increment
```

and it is showing

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: dashback-backend@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: mongoose@8.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
npm ERR!   mongoose@"~8.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer mongoose@"~8.1.0" from @typegoose/auto-increment@4.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@typegoose/auto-increment
npm ERR!   @typegoose/auto-increment@"*" from the root project      
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

what are the compatiable versions for this?

i dont want to update nestjs to higher version because this may break the code!